# 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the on Install Mysql

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

i step by step [Install Mysql](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-apache-with-php-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04-lamp/) on my VPS

but i have this error:

```
root@euve838129:~# apt-get -y install mysql-server mysql-client
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you run the given command? (`dpkg --configure -a`)
Most times, this fixes the issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually telling Package manager dpkg was interrupted for some reason.

Try to solve this by the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

If this doesn't work, `sudo apt-get install -f` will meet the unmet dependencies.

Comment: You should add a `;` between `dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get update`. Otherwise bash supplies `sudo apt-get update` as arguments to `dpkg` which will raise an error.